# When is it right to create a new repository from HEAD?

Tags: svn, version-control

I created a repository last August, I've been using it for a year.  I'm up to about 900 commits.  I'm starting to wonder if I should recreate a new Repository.

This is not something I would do every year.

I was very new to subversion last year and I made a LOT of mistakes....

Most of those mistakes relate to loading files that should not have been loaded.  Like video files and such.  Making my repository VERY VERY big.

Also, I was clueless on merges, and I broke alot of the tracking by not merging properly.

### So, I'm thinking I should start a new.....

Take my `HEAD` and begin again.

Now here are some random brainstorming thoughts related to this.

- I could still keep the old repo, and just set it to Read Only.
- Can I maintain the history in the NEW repo, but not the data?
- If I start over, is it like a checkbook?  Can I order the new repo to start at some number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is history there that is useless to you and just wasting space, then creating a new repo is a good idea. There are lots of ways to approach this depending on how much SVN you know, but a straightforward way is to check out an older revision that you want to be your starting point, then create a new repo from that, check out the next revision, commit, and repeat.

Of course you will need to write some tools to help with this. When you check out that old revision, there are lots of hidden .svn directories containing metadata. So, don't do `svn checkout <url>` , instead, do `svn export <url>`. It will export your files except the .svn metadata directories. Use that to create the new repo.

Then, copy these files to a already checked out new repo. Then simply do a svn add of these files. Then, commit it, and you are done.

It might be a good idea to drive that process from a text file listing all the revision numbers, one per line. That way if you want to skip over a bunch that are related to merge problems, it is easy to do so.

You could probably do the whole thing just with bash shell scripts, but if you have some skill with a scripting language like Python etc., then you might find that easier than bash.

Don't forget to collect the log message for each revision, and add that when you commit to the new repo. Most svn commands take a `-r` option so you can do something like `svn log -r 334` to get the log message for only revision 334.

Comment: Michael, in order to obtain a revision without the `.svn` subfolders you just have to do an export and specify the revision number, you don't need any special tool for that. Other than that your advices are ok :)

Comment: If you are happy starting the new repo with a revision after the experimentation, that is fine, but you can also skip revisions to avoid big binary files. If you checked in the file in revision 23 and deleted it in 178 then you can keep 1-22 and then skip to 24 which means the new repo will not have the big deleted binary in it. Your choice.